# Печать значений макросов в читаемом виде

Tags: c++, макросы

Условный пример, есть группы макросов (таких групп около 20 по проекту + неизвестное количество из винапи):

```
#define DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE    0x00
#define DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE     0x01
#define DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE  0x02
```

Может быть существует какой-либо способ при выводе на печать (в лог, в консоль) получить именно имя макроса, чтобы в логе было что-то вроде:

```
DtrControl: [0х01] DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE
```

Текущая реализация: функции `<value_type>to_str`, внутри у каждой из которых switch блок, вида:

```
switch (dcb.fDtrControl)
{
case DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE:   tmp = "DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE";   break;
case DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE:    tmp = "DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE";    break;
case DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE: tmp = "DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE"; break;
default: tmp = QString("Unknown [%1]").arg(dcb.fDtrControl);
}
```

Буду благодарен за любые советы как можно упростить, сделать понятнее, проще и читабельнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Си - не мой основной язык, поэтому мой вариант может быть субоптимальным, но можно сделать нечто подобное на макросах:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOO_1 1
#define FOO_2 2

#define STR_(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_(x)
#define FOO_STR(x) "[" STR(x) "] " #x

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", FOO_STR(FOO_1));
    printf("%s\n", FOO_STR(FOO_2));
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
[1] FOO_1
[2] FOO_2
```